# VALUE NOT EXIST (SQL)

Tags: sql, plsql

I wrote this simple code:

---

```
DECLARE 

    Y NUMBER;
    B EMP.ENAME%TYPE;

BEGIN

    Y :=:ENTER_NO;

    SELECT ENAME INTO B
    FROM EMP
    WHERE EMPNO = Y;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(B) ;

END;
```

---

And this code works ok, but how can I print a message when the user enters a number not found in the database?

Comment: No need for <caps lock>.

Comment: There is no need to SHOUT here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use exceptions. Try this:

```
DECLARE 
    y NUMBER;
    b emp.ename%TYPE;
BEGIN
    y := :enter_no;
    SELECT ename INTO b
        FROM emp
        WHERE empno = y;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(b);
END;
```